# Crosswords - Feline rage

Tags: word, crosswords

Here's a crosswords puzzle grid:

[image: Crosswords grid]

---

**Horizontal clues**

> **1)** The better thing that can happen to a recruit
>
> **7)** Local Area Network
>
> **8)** Ante Meridian
>
> **10)** Not out
>
> **11)** Grip tightly and sharply between finger and thumb
>
> **14)** A type of precipitation
>
> **15)** A famous plushes
>
> **17)** That's negative
>
> **19)** Gentle___ (plural)
>
> **21)** RPG, but it's only R
>
> **23)** Russian domain (*i. e. puzzling.stackexchange.**com***)
>
> **24)** A Microsoft Word's documents extension
>
> **25)** Romanian domain (*i. e. puzzling.stackexchange.**com***)

---

**Vertical clues**

> **1)** A Microsoft tool included with the Operating System that allows you to draw
>
> **2)** Office Lady
>
> **3)** A diagrammatic area representation that may include roads, parks and other stuff
>
> **4)** Bulb composed of several concentric layers
>
> **5)** Unit used to measure monitors size
>
> **6)** Not a Number, but without Number
>
> **9)** Large shopping center
>
> **12)** The space just inside the front entrance of a house or flat
>
> **13)** A lyric poem
>
> **16)** Australian bird with three-toed feet
>
> **18)** Like Shrek
>
> **20)** Not Defined
>
> **22)** Exclamation that express hesitation

---

**How to play**

> After have solved the crossword, in the colored fields will appear two words: to complete them, you must keep in mind a `G` for each word
>
> *Remember that azure fields are for the first word, while the yellow ones are for the last)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grid (sorry for crude drawing):

> [image]

By assembling coloured letters to words, we get

> *TIGER RAMPAGE* (adding Gs to both words, we get a synonym for the title).

Comment: Assuming 21th word is Role and not Rule, the crossword is completely correct, like the final answer you have provided, well done

Comment: Yes, it's "role". Sorry for the ambiguous 2nd letter.